# .PDF and .JPG assets not downloading with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webclient, client-side-scripting

I'd like to have assets available for download on my site via JavaScript. This is the code I currently have:

```
//Creates an iFrame and adds ID to it to download
var downloadURL = function downloadURL(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
        iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;
};
```

This creates an iframe if none is present, gives the iFrame the ID of "hiddenIFrameID" and downloads it, client side. This currently is working to download .psd and .ai files but cannot interpret the file when it calls to download .jpg or .pdf's. Any advice? Here is the structure of my HTML:

```
<a onclick="downloadURL('imagepath.jpg');">Download</a>
```

Comment: It will likely just show the files in the iframe if the browser can render them. Which won;t happen for PSD or AI files.

Comment: You'll need to have access to server side to change the file's headers.

Comment: There isn't a server, this is all local (file://)

Answer (score 1):

To force some file (e.g. image, PDF, etc) be downloaded instead of just rendered/displayed by browser:

1. Either change server-side. The file should be accompanied with [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header. This can be done for example, with `.htaccess` files.
2. Or use [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute of links. For example, `<a href="imagepath.jpg" download>Download</a>`.

   - You can even initiate download from within script by creating hidden link and calling its `click()` method.

Comment: Is there something more cro-bro friendly? I am not using a server

Comment: @KristinaRobinson, it's HTML5, it should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: (@KristinaRobinson, oops, I see Safari (and MSIE<13) doesn't support it yet. Sorry, I don't have other solution. I'd either wait until they release fixed versions or use server-side header.))

Comment: @KristinaRobinson, what does it mean that you're not using a server? HTTP always uses a server. Or, are you accessing HTMLs from local computer through "file:" scheme?

Comment: Everything is local as of now, we are trying to avoid using a server

Comment: @KristinaRobinson, does "local" mean you're using `file://` (not `http://`) scheme? Then why do you need downloading at all?

Comment: Yes. This project is to make downloads user-friendly without having to go into the folder itself.